# Google Chrome SVG data URI

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, svg

I have an issue with the following code on Google Chrome (it's working in Firefox)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <title>Test load jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <object id="alphasvg"></object>    
    </body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        var svg = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' id='svgid'><circle cx='40' cy='40' r='24' style='stroke:#006600; fill:#00cc00'/></svg>";
        var encodedString = btoa(svg);
        var svgdataencoded = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + encodedString;
        $('#alphasvg').attr('data', svgdataencoded);

        var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");        
        a.addEventListener("load", function() {
            var svg = a.contentDocument.getElementById("svgid");
            console.log(svg);
        }, false);

    </script>
</html>
```

Google Chrome outputs the following error

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLObjectElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://server.mydomain.com:8080" from accessing a frame with origin "null". The
>   frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

Do you have any solution to resolve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: You have the SVG before it loads so if you want to change it then you could always change the original data and reload that as the data attribute. It's that or write a Chrome patch and submit it I suppose.

Comment: It's a sample code to debug the error message from Chrome. The SVG is loaded asynchronously in my production code. Anyway Chrome complains about the protocol between http: and data: